Sensor fusion in ROS2: 360 lidar + depth camera
I recently purchased an OAKD-Lite camera and I'm trying to integrate it into my ROS 2-operated robot to detect obstacles that are lower than the 360lidar, preventing collisions. So far, I've succeeded in incorporating the camera's point cloud into both the local and global cost maps. However, I've noticed that the navigation and path planning algorithms aren't giving as much consideration to obstacles detected by the camera compared to those detected by the 360 lidar. I have tried with a much simple depth camera but the issue is still there
Additionally, I've come across the concept of sensor fusion, and I'm interested in implementing it, but so far, I have only seen ROS implementations. Has anyone successfully implemented sensor fusion with depth camera in their project, or does anyone know of any resources or guides that could help?
Thank you in advance.
For a more in depth explanation: obstacles are detected by the camera and translated into the local and global coastmap but, the path planing is done too close to the obstacle, sometimes even on top of it and when the robot goes too close/bumps on the obstacle it kinda clears from the map. Sometimes, the robots even follows a path to avoid the obstacle, turns around, stops seeing the obstacle, clears the maps, and as now it thinks its now there, it clears and again goes on top of the obstacle colliding. This does not happens with the 360 lidar and the path planing works perfectly. I have tried to play with some parameters as the inflation and the cost but none seems to have effect.

You can use packages like Rtabmap. Rtabmap is originally built for vslam but it supports data fusion from all other sources which gives you the ability to fuse scan data along with rgb and depth data.
